# ImportError: cannot import name UART

Tags: python, xbee, micropython

I am trying to use the UART library in micropython XBEE, but it gives me an error in the import.

This is my code:

```
from machine import UART

uart = UART(1, 9600)                         # init with given baudrate
uart.init(9600, bits=8, parity=None, stop=1) # init with given parameters
uart.read()
```

This is the error:

```
from machine import UART
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name UART
```

Regards.

Comment: How did you install micropython?

Comment: I am using micropython in XBEE, the micropython already has it installed.

Comment: The ImportError suggests that you don't actually have it installed. Specifically, within the `machine` namespace, there is no `UART` class. Can you try `import machine`, then call `dir()` and share the output? I'm wondering if anything is there.

Comment: This is the output:  " ['__name__', 'stdin', '_', 'machine', 'stdout'] "

Comment: OK, and what does `dir(machine)` give you?

Comment: This is the output: '['__class__', '__name__', 'ADC', 'BROWNOUT_RESET', 'HARD_RESET', 'I2C', 'LOCKUP_RESET', 'PWM', 'PWRON_RESET', 'Pin', 'SOFT_RESET', 'Signal', 'WDT_RESET', 'reset', 'reset_cause', 'rng', 'soft_reset', 'unique_id']'

Comment: So this explains the `ImportError`. There is a `machine` module, you can import it, but there's no `UART` class or member. Looking at the [Digi Micropython Programming Guide](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/PDFs/90002219.pdf) page 91, it looks like you _should_ be able to `from machine import UART`. Page 90 says "NoteThis section only applies to devices that support the Secondary UART feature". Have you verified that includes your device?